# Do the class vector and character vector of a $p$-group determine each other?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, p-groups

To a finite $p$-group, we can associate two vectors $(v_0,v_1,\dotsc)$:

1. The class vector - $v_i$ is the number of conjugacy classes of order $p^i$.
2. The character vector - $v_i$ is the number of complex irreducible representations of dimension $i$ up to isomorphism.

Question: Do these two invariants of the group determine each other? In other words, if two groups have the same class vector, do they have the same character vector and vice versa?

---

Comment: @ToddLeason Should have tried that before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. This observation is cataloged at the Group Properties Wiki on pages [1](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_statistics_need_not_determine_degrees_of_irreducible_representations) and [2](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Degrees_of_irreducible_representations_need_not_determine_conjugacy_class_size_statistics).

> It is possible to have two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that the conjugacy class size statistics of $G_1$ are the same as those of $G_2$ (i.e., the two groups have the same number of conjugacy classes of each size) but the Degrees of irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}$ for $G_1$ are not the same as those of $G_2$...
>
> It is possible to have two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that the multiset of Degrees of irreducible representations (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $G_1$ is the same as the multiset of degrees of irreducible representations of $G_2$ (i.e., $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same number of irreducible representations of each degree) but the conjugacy class size statistics of $G_1$ and $G_2$ are not the same...

Further, the smallest example of the first statement is of size $128$, while for the other statement, examples of groups of size $64$ exist so that these statements are true for $p$-groups as well.

Comment: In the GAP small groups library, the groups with ID (128,1758) and (128,2022) have the same class vector: $(2,14,48,64)$. However, their character vectors are $(16,12,0,1)$ and $(16,8,5,0)$, respectively.

Comment: In the GAP small groups library, the groups with ID (64,4) and (64,257) have the same character vectors (16,4,2), but their class vectors are (4,6,12) and (2,9,11) respectively.